# Problem with schema synchronization using Import Replica Schema (Data Management)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7, replication

I want to synchronize the schema of replica. The steps I am following is documented in [ArcGIS Resources](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000001q000000):

1. Export the geodatabase_1 replica schema using [Export Replica Schema (Data Management) tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000001n000000).
2. Compare the schema of geodatabase_1 and geodatabase_2 replica using [Compare Replica Schema (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000015000000)
3. Import the compared schema (.xml) to geodatabase_2 replica using [Import Replica Schema (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000001q000000)

Code sample to import is:

```
def import_schema(admin_sde, geodatabase_2, in_replica, schema):
    """import compared replica schema to geodatabase
    :param admin_sde: admin connection to disconnect users
    :param geodatabase_2: import schema to geodatabase
    :param in_replica: import schema for replica
    :param schema: schema xml
    """
    try:
        replica_list = arcpy.da.ListReplicas(geodatabase_2)
        replica_user = (user.name.split(".")[0] for user in replica_list
                        if user.name.split(".")[-1] == in_replica.split(".")[-1]).next()
        connected_users = [con_user for con_user in arcpy.ListUsers(admin_sde)
                           if con_user.ClientName != socket.gethostname()]
        log.info('Pausing user connection to geo-database: "{}"\n'.format(geodatabase_2))
        arcpy.AcceptConnections(admin_sde, False)
        log.info('Disconnecting users except for: "{}" and "SDE" from the geo-database: "{}"\n'.format(replica_user,
                                                                                                       geodatabase_2))
        for user in connected_users:
            arcpy.DisconnectUser(admin_sde, user.ID)
        log.info('Importing schema file to geo-database: "{0}" on replica: "{1}"\n'.format(geodatabase_2, in_replica))
        result = arcpy.ImportReplicaSchema_management(geodatabase_2, schema)
        return result
    except Exception as error:
        log.error(error)
    finally:
        log.info('Resuming geo-database: "{}"\n'.format(geodatabase_2))
        arcpy.AcceptConnections(admin_sde, True)
```

When I import the compared schema through python script, it adds the new fields to geodatabase_2 but do not delete the fields which are already been deleted in geodatabase_1. This leads to too many unwanted fields in the geodatabase_2 replica. While working on ArcMap (Distributed Geodatabase -> Import Schema Changes), it opens a **`Import Schema Changes Wizard`** where we can select the dropped fields and apply the schema changes to geodatabase_2. How to achieve this via python script? I want the same schema should reflect at geodatabase_2 replica after importing compared schema.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Does anybody has the answer.
One more addition to it :
How the domain owner plays role while performing schema sync?
Im also getting an error for one replica saying -
'Existing Domain Owner does not match that of the updated domain owner' Looking for urgent solution!!

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Hemlata! Could you please ask this as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead of posting it as an _answer_? You can always add a link to this post in your question for reference =)